# How do I solve this functional equation? $ f ( m + n ) = f ( m ) + f ( n ) + 2 m n $ where $ f ( n ) $ is always a perfect square

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $ f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $ such that
>
> (a) $ f ( n ) $ is a square for each $ n \in \mathbb N $;
> (b) $ f ( m  + n ) = f ( m ) + f ( n ) + 2 m n $, for all $ m , n \in \mathbb N $.

Clearly $f(x)=x^2$ is one such function, but is it the only one? If yes, then how can I prove it?

Comment: You have the ([tag:contest-math]) tag. Is this from a contest?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, It's from a textbook for math Olympiads.

Comment: As $f(n)$ is always a square, we can write $f(n)=g(n)^2$, then $g(m+n)^2=g(m)^2+g(n)^2+2mn$, reducing it to one equation that we have to solve...

Comment: @Markus Zetto, I'm sorry I don't understand how substituting $f(n)=g(n)^2$ helps

Comment: @Markus Zetto Ok, now I understand how it helps, but how do I go about solving for g(x)?

Comment: This question without condition (a) is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183340/find-functions-f-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-such-that-fmn-fmfn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeals the "Taiwanese Transformation".

As pointed by Markus Zetto, we will let $f(x)=g(x)^2$ and then "translate by the obvious solution" $f(x)=x^2$, i.e., set $h(x)=g(x)^2-x^2$.
You can rewrie the equation as $g(m+n)^2-(m+n)^2=(g(m)^2-m^2)+(g(n^2)-n^2)$ which thus returns $h(m+n)=h(m)+h(n)$ and note that its a Cauchy Equation which is bounded, and hence it is linear, thus $h(x)=ax+c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$, but substituiting this in the original equation clearly gives $c=0$, thus $f(x)=x^2+ax$ for some $a\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and note that $x^2+ax$ cannot be a square for every $x$ as $a$ is fixed, and thus the only solution is $f(x)=x^2$ which works.